# Inkscape ignores <use>

Tags: svg, inkscape

Importing the following SVG file in Inkscape show only the text but ignores the `<use>` statement (or the group referenced by it). Is it a bug or a feature? Anything to change?  BTW, the `<g>` group is more complex of the one in the example file. The file is correctly shown in Chrome. (Windows 10, Inkscape latest)

Thanks!
mario

```
<svg width="400" height="200" x="0" y="0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <g id="plus">
    <circle cx="40" cy="30" r="20" stroke="#FF0000" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
</defs>
<svg x="100" y="50">
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="78" height="86" rx="10" ry="10" stroke="#0000FF" fill="none"></rect>
  <use href="#plus"></use>
  <text x="20" y="74" width="68" height="26">ABCD</text>
</svg>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

`<use href="#plus">` should be `<use xlink:href="#plus">`. Plus you will need to add an `xmlns:xlink` attribute to your root SVG tag.

```
<svg width="400" height="200" x="0" y="0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
  <g id="plus">
    <circle cx="40" cy="30" r="20" stroke="#FF0000" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
</defs>
<svg x="100" y="50">
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="78" height="86" rx="10" ry="10" stroke="#0000FF" fill="none"></rect>
  <use xlink:href="#plus"></use>
  <text x="20" y="74" width="68" height="26">ABCD</text>
</svg>
</svg>
```

If you make those fixes, the file loads into Inkscape.

Comment: It is fantastic! It works! Thanks a lot. I have to say this is not clearly shown in the SVG documentation. Now I have to check if the editor exporting these SVG can be simply modified and if it continues to work with these changes. Thanks again! mario

Comment: It's specified at the bottom of [section 17.1.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#linking-xlinkRefAttrs) and in [Appendix G.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#conform-ConformingSVGDocuments).

Comment: OK found, but in [SVG2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/linking.html#XLinkRefAttrs) `xlink:href` is marked as deprecated. Anyway, problem solved and I'm happy.

Comment: Old question, but you might know - does Inkscape have a UI for `<use>` or is it a matter of keeping the XML editor open?

Comment: I believe it uses `<use>` elements when working with symbols (see [SymbolsDialog](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SymbolsDialog). But that is probably only w.r.t. symbols specifically. I'm not sure how it handles `<use>` elements that reference non `<symbol>` references. Sorry.